# Memory leak in NetTrain?

Tags: memory, machine-learning, neural-networks

**Issue**

`NetTrain` seems to leak memory.

**Example**

We define a simple `NetChain`:

```
net = NetInitialize@NetChain[{5, LogisticSigmoid, 1}, "Input" -> 3];
```

We define the input data:

```
hues = RandomReal[1, {1000000, 1}];
rgbs = List @@ ColorConvert[Hue[#[[1]]], "RGB"] & /@ hues;
rules = Inner[Rule, Hold @@@ rgbs, Hold @@@ hues, List] /. 
   Hold -> List;
```

The memory used, according to *Mathematica*:

```
MemoryInUse[]

(* 373849120 *)
```

My task manager shows 412.0 MB used.

---

Now we train the net:

```
net = NetTrain[net, rules, BatchSize -> 512, MaxTrainingRounds -> 5]
```

And we check the memory usage:

```
MemoryInUse[]

(* 444727112 *) (* ~70MB increase *)
```

My task manager shows 497.1 MB (~85MB increase).

So far, it seems okay. *Mathematica* had to load `NeuralNetworks` things, so it seems natural that the memory usage increased.

---

Now we train the net more (it doesn't matter if you generate new `rules`):

```
net = NetTrain[net, rules, BatchSize -> 512, MaxTrainingRounds -> 5]
```

The memory usage doesn't really change:

```
MemoryInUse[]

(* 444963728 *)
```

But in the task manager, *Mathematica* is now using 517.1 MB (20MB increase).

**Question**

What is causing the increase in memory allocation of *Mathematica*?

Comment: When I train a large neural net, the memory leak becomes more severe; _Mathematica_ takes over 8 GB of RAM while it thinks it is using only about 200 MB.

Comment: What's your platform? Windows?

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon `"11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"`

Answer (score 4):

For CPU usage, the answer is simple: the learning backend (customized version of MXNet) uses the MKL library on CPUs, which is parallelized and utilizes all available cores. That's a good thing!

The memory usage, please try the following: before you run anything, set `$HistoryLength = 0`. Does that improve matters? Also, after training, see if running `` NeuralNetworks`ClearCache[] `` changes what Task Manager shows.

Last thing that would help us track down what's going on here, can you run the following code (on a fresh kernel) and paste its output a) before training b) after the first NetTrain c) after the second NetTrain?

```
AssociationMap[
  MXNetLink`GetManagedLibraryKeys /* Length, 
  {"MXExecutor", "NDArray", "MXSymbol", "MXOptimizer"}]
```

Comment: My `$HistoryLength` is already `0`. ``NeuralNetworks`ClearCache[]`` doesn't seem to do anything. For your code, the output before training is `<|"MXExecutor" -> 1, "NDArray" -> 1, "MXSymbol" -> 1, 
 "MXOptimizer" -> 1|>`. The outputs after the first training and the second training are `<|"MXExecutor" -> 0, "NDArray" -> 0, "MXSymbol" -> 0, 
 "MXOptimizer" -> 0|>`.

Comment: @JHM I'm inclined to think that this is a false positive. For example, memory allocated and deallocated during training (though there shouldn't be much) might cause the heap to become fragmented, and the OS is unable to reclaim it from the application. What actual pain is it causing you?

Comment: I have to export the net and restart the kernel more than 80 times if I want to train my net with all data available.

Comment: @JHM go in chatroom?

Comment: Sure. How do I join?

Comment: @JHM actually it's a bit late (past midnight) for me. if you contact support and mentioned this conversation we can shift the discussion to email. Sounds like there is a real problem here and my colleagues and I should be able to diagnose what might be happening with some simple experiments. hopefully we can get this into the 10.0.1 release if we can find the problem quickly.

Comment: Alright. Should I mention your name in the e-mail?

Comment: @JHM yes do that

Comment: I have not received any replies from the support desk (I sent two e-mails)... What is causing the issue in my question? Also, is it fixed in 11.0.1?

Comment: Any solutions? I am trying to train on a large dataset in mathematica 12 and my machine runs out of RAM when I use a generator function.